# Excel ActiveX ListBox Shrinks with each update

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a set of linked subs which work like this:

1. A user types into an ActiveX TextBox
2. A Change Event in that TextBox calls a sub in a Module
3. That Module sub drives updating a named range in a sheet
4. The range value drives updating a table of Excel cells that uses lookup functions based on the range value
5. The table values are copied and pasted to a another range (to eliminate links to formulas)
6. That pasted range is put into a ListBox using this (props to Rory for his patience):

   ActiveSheet.ListBox1.List = Sheets("Search Criteria Control").Range("G1:G21").Value

The result is that for every character the user types in the TextBox the ListBox is updated.

The problem I have is that the ListBox shrinks a bit with every keystroke in the TextBox referred to in #1 above.  Is this normal behavior and I'm misusing ListBoxes, am I doing something wrong or do I need to respecify the dimensions of the ListBox every time it is updated with something like this?

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Top = 35
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Left = 650
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Width = 550
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Height = 610
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on this.

Comment: This is a common and very longstanding bug with ActiveX controls on worksheets. You'll need to reset them explicitly in your code, or use Form controls instead which are generally more stable.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/759980-list-box-changing-sizes.html) help?

Comment: Ok, thanks Rory.  Are Form controls clickable so you can drive other code to run?

Comment: David, thank you also.  Setting the IntegralHeight to False stopped the resizing.

Answer (score 13):

I was having trouble with the same thing.  My ActiveX listbox would move around on the sheet and change size for no reason that I could see.

While I did go ahead and develop some code to reset size and coordinates, that wasn't satisfactory since there had to be a mechanism to trigger that code - something I didn't want to burden end-users with.

I found a better answer in another user forum.  There's a Listbox Property called **`IntegralHeight`** whose default property is `True` - something to do with screen resolution and optimal display of listbox contents.  Simply set that to `False`.  I did that with some ActiveX boxes that were giving me fits, and I was able to disable the "adjustment" code and, so far, so good!